# Correct encoding into "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: linux, http, post, curl

The Debian command-line tool `curl` doesn't seem capable to perform a compliant data encoding into *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.

From `man curl` I get the following list of encoding options:

**Option:**                                        **Purpose:**

```
-d/--data <data>            send non-encoded data as x-www-form-urlencoded
--data-binary <data>        send raw data as x-www-form-urlencoded
--data-urlencode <data>     send url-encoded data as x-www-form-urlencoded
-F/--form <name=content>    send data as multipart/form-data
```

As the encode `urlencode` differs from `x-www-form-urlencoded` for multiple reasons, such as the encode of spaces, which is `%20` for the former and `+` for the latter, can `curl` perform a compliant `x-www-form-urlencoded` encode?

Comment: as i understand %20 is compliant for www-form-urlencoded as any character encoded with % will be decoded correct way

Comment: Wikipedia on x-www-form-urlencoded_type:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type

Comment: I mean - yes curl adds %20 instead of `+` but %20 should be parsed correct by any www-form-urlencoded parser, so it is not a problem, check bug tracking with curl, the problem could be here if `+` would to be transfered as `+` by curl, but it is transfered as `%2B`

Comment: Thanks Stenberg, I corrected the post.